# PHP calling function from another file not working

Tags: php, ajax

Very basically, I'm trying to set the value of a variable in one file based on the return value of a function in another file. This is then returned via AJAX, however, the AJAX always seems to indicate an error. Code below:

updateTurn.php

```
<?php
//This is called by AJAX
require_once('functions.php'); //include necessary file
$player = getCurrentTurn(); //call function 
echo $player;
?>
```

functions.php

```
...
function getCurrentTurn()
{
    //the query and connection function appropriately
    include_once("getConn.php");
    $query = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare("SELECT turn FROM Game");
    $query->execute();
    $result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result['turn']; //return the result of the query
}
...
```

AJAX

```
function checkForTurnChange(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"updateTurn.php",
        async:true,
        cache:false,
        timeout:10000,
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        //this is where AJAX is returning
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus +": "+ errorThrown);
        }
    });//end AJAX
};//end function
```

The error is caused by the line `$player = getCurrentTurn();`. If I remove this and `echo` any string value then it works correctly. This is incredibly basic but I can't seem to see my error. All help appreciated.

EDIT: The AJAX calls `error:` which results in this `alert` :

[image: AJAX error message]

Comment: is the defination of `getCurrentTurn()` contained in a class in functions.php file?

Comment: @Sourabh no, the file simply contains functions only. As far as I can see, there is no need for me to instantiate any objects.

Comment: yes not need if you do not intend to do so, can post what is the response you are getting from your ajax call?

Comment: Edited to show AJAX response

Comment: are all the files in the same directory? You're `error` callback is being fired that points to an `http` error

Comment: Yep, same directory. If I keep the `include` but remove the function call and `echo "test";` then it works perfectly

Comment: What happens if you call `updateTurn.php` directly in your browser (no ajax call)

Comment: has this variable `$result['turn']` got any value in it

Comment: @harpax calling it in the browser just results in a blank page. @Sourabh yes, if I copy the implementation of `getCurrentTurn()` into `updateTurn.php` then it functions as expected. I need to reuse this implementation, hence the encapsulation into an independent function. The issue seems to lie in the call to `getCurrentTurn()` from a different file.

Comment: yes check that function correctly, if that will execute successfully then your issue will be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resolved:

Removed `include("getConn.php");` from `getCurrentTurn()` within `functions.php` and relocated it to be available for the entire file, not just locally available for that function. Therefore, `functions.php` should be:

```
include("getConn.php");
...
function getCurrentTurn()
{
$query = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare("SELECT turn FROM Game");
$query->execute();
$result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $result['turn'];
}
...
```